# Regex negative lookbehind with optional space?

Tags: regex

i'm trying to figure out regex pattern for catching numerical values with optional sign, but it should not catch range. So i thought that i need to check in lookbehind if there is number procceding sign, but it doesnt work well with optional spaces. Here is my regex:

```
((?<![0-9])(\s?[-+]\s?))?([0-9]+)
```

And here example:

```
foo -20    < catches (-20) | good
0 - 20    < catches (0,-20) | wrong should catch (0,20)
foobar, 2-20 < catches (2,20) | good
bar, 2 - 20  < catches (2,-20) | wrong should catch (2,20)
+20       < catches (+20) | good
    -20       < catches (-20) | good
foo bar,-20,foo       < catches (-20) | good
```

Comment: Since you check for 1 or 0 spaces between the numbers, I think `(?:(?<!\d )(?<!\d)[-+])?[0-9]+` can work for you.

Comment: If this is for Python an idea using [conditional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html): [`((?<=\d) *- *)?((?(1)|[+-] *)?\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/imOmLI/2) (catpures in second group). This is meant to work with arbitrary amount of spaces.

Comment: You already have an answer and 2 good suggestions, but if `2 -20` is not a range perhaps `(?:\B[+-])?\b\d+` See https://regex101.com/r/bILgLI/1

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your regex flavor so I'll assume PCRE.

You could use something like this with intelligent grouping. You'll notice that I didn't attempt lookbehinds because variable-width lookbehinds are not universally supported and some flavors have hacks which don't work in other flavors.

```
(?<first>[+-]?\d+)(?:\s*-\s*(?<second>[+-]?\d+))?
```

- `(?<first>[+-]?\d+)` - find the first integer and place it into a named capture group; it can be positive, negative, or have no denotation
- `(?:\s*-\s*(?<second>[+-]?\d+))?` - optionally, match a range which follows the first integer and place the second integer into a named capture group

  - `(?:` - open non-capture group
  - `\s*-\s*` - a range is denoted as a dash with possible whitespace surrounding it
  - `(?<second>[+-]?\d+)` - capture the second integer; it can be positive, negative,  or have no denotation
  - `)?` - close the non-capturing group and make its contents optional

https://regex101.com/r/fSmBM9/1